# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "١2" Problem with numbers processing in Persian

Tags: java, double

getting an error of invalid Double When typing into Persian numbers
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٢3"

```
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        numberEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        String text = numberEditText.getText().toString();

        text = text.replace(",", "");

        if (text.length() > 0){
            DecimalFormat sdd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

                Double doublenumber = Double.parseDouble(text);

            String format = sdd.format(doublenumber);
            numberEditText.setText(format);
            numberEditText.setSelection(format.length());
        }

        numberEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: NumberFormats such as DecimalFormat are for parsing localized numbers.  Double.parseDouble (like nearly all parse methods in java.lang) will only parse numbers as they are allowed to appear in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the locale on your `DecimalFormat`. You can do this using the [`NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale locale)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)) method. At the top of the documentation for [`DecimalFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat), it explicitly explains how to utilize NumberFormat to get a DecimalFormat with locale.

EDIT: As Stephen stated in the comments, this is only half of the solution, the other half is to use the `DecimalFormat` object to parse the string into a number. So the code will look like:

```
Locale decimalFormatLocale = YOUR_LOCALE_HERE;
DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(decimalFormatLocale);

double formattedNumber = decimalFormatter.parse(text, new ParsePosition(0)); //the position here should be the position in the String variable text that the number starts.
```

Comment: This is only half of the solution.  The other half is that you must use the format to **parse** the number.